# How to update image preview(icon)?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I have a *UIList* with a property that uses the preview icon of an image as its icon. It works, but it doesn't update, unless the icon is updated somewhere else first, i.e. in the texture paint slots or the Image Editor'' selector. Is there a way to make it update?

**edit-** I was told that image previews are updated when a dependency update is triggered on them. Does anyone know how to do this in Python?

Comment: I don't know if [this](http://www.sinestesia.co/tutorials/making-uilists-in-blender/) will help, but it might. Good luck!

Comment: Well this isn't a UIList problem, its an icon update problem. I'm very familiar with that tutorial. Thanks a lot for responding though.

Comment: This is supported by the API. Giving a code-example that doesn't work properly would help here.

Comment: I can't give a code example that doesn't work because my code works. I don't have any code that says "when this image is changed, update its preview" because I don't know how. That is what the question is. If you know how, I would be grateful if you shared.

Comment: I would love to get an answer for that question too! :)